# Selecting Parent of Element Using JQuery selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to find the count of **TD** inside my **TR** where one of its **TD** matches my criteria .
Here is the skeleton of my html structure,

```
<div class="pager">
        <table class="pager_table">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td id ="sometextPager_left"></td>
                    <td></td>
                ...................
        </table>
    </div>
```

And my JQuery selector code is:

```
$('div.pager > table.pager-table td[id$="Pager_left"] :parent tr > td').length
```

It seems my selector is not working,

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `:has()` selector,

```
$('div.pager > table.pager-table tr:has(td[id$="Pager_left"]) > td').length
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have class attribute on div.

Change 1st row to this:

```
<div class="pager">
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `:parent` selector a jQuery selectors are evaluated right-to left. Having a parent selector would require right-to-left evaluation.

Assuming you have no other TDs with ID attributes, you can simply check for the existence of an `ID` attribute on a `TD` with `td[id]` and target its parent row using `:has()`

```
$('.pager > .pager_table tr:has(td[id]) > td').length // returns 3
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/ghLcyp54/1